# Chaining asynchronous events with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

Given a list of actions thats each triggers an asynchronous event, how do I execute them all with a guaranteed ordering:

```
$.each(actions, function(i, action) {
    action.execute(); // triggers an asynch process;
                      // how do I ensure that the next action isn't triggered until the current completes? 
});
```

One thought I had was to have the completion of each asynch execution fire off a custom event, but I was unsure of how to structure the logic given the need to trigger these in a loop for each action in the list:

```
$.each(actions, function(i, action) {       
    action.on('executed', function() {
       // continue on to next action; but how to structure this? 
       // In other words, how to sequentially chain a non-fixed # of callbacks?
    });
    action.execute(); 
});
```

Comment: Take a look at jQuery `Deferred`, especially the `when` method.

Comment: But I don't want to execute a callback when all events are done; rather, I want to ensure that each next action is only executed when the previous event completes.  Doesn't deferred still lead to the same problem I presented since there isn't a fixed number of actions?

Answer (score 0):

With this:

```
(function execAction(i){   
   if( i >= actions.length) return;  //When all has finished, do nothing
   actions[i].execute(function(yourCallbackParams){
      execAction(i+1);
   });
})(0); //Start with i == 0
```

Assuming `.execute` receives a callback as parameter

Cheers